# Javascript prompt to confirm reopen when voting "leave closed"

Tags: bug, status-completed

[image]

This happened when I reviewed the question as "leave closed".  It's rather confusing.  I clicked cancel, and my review was registered and it moved to the next item. ***Le bug!***